# How to resolve network issue or DNS to access web page on Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: network, osx-server, dns

I have my network setup like as follows:

internet > router 1 > ethernet ports > switch > router 2

I have a Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server connected to "router 1", but it is so slow when accessing a web page hosted on the server from a browser on a workstation connected to either router 1 or router 2?

Is there a problem with my network setup or maybe because I changed the name to newservername.local?

Comment: Don't name your server with the .local extension. Bad things happen, as the .local extension is reserved for Bonjour services. Change it back.

Answer (score 1):

This would most commonly be a problem with [MTU sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit). Try setting yours to something a bit smaller (1450 or so), you can do this under the **Hardware** tab in **Network preferences**.